# Voltage and current for travel kettle

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I used a 500 watt travel kettle in France last year and it tripped the electrics in my hotel room so I stopped using it. I assumed the current was too high, even though its wattage rating wasn't that high.

However I realised the voltage switch on the kettle was set to 120V and not 240V (the voltage in France).

Would the travel kettle have used more current as it was set to 120V? If it didn't have a voltage switch, it'd surely use less current at a higher voltage, but I'm wondering if the voltage switch being on the wrong voltage caused an issue here?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE. Maybe your question would be more appropriate on electrical engineering SE ? Anyway it would be great if you could ask your question in a more general way without the most specific detail, it would better fit the policy of the forum. 
To briefly answer you, yes. If on 120V it needs half the current it gets on 230V to get the same power (wattage) therefore it's resistance is lower draining more current than it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a good question and I think the key is understanding what the **voltage switch** on the kettle **does**. Realize that current in the kettle is not bound to the *power* of the kettle by $P=VI$ rather the actual voltage and current is related by (approximate) Ohm's Law: $$V=IR$$
Notice that I will show show the voltage switch changes the **resistance** of the kettle circuits. Think in your situation when you put the voltage knob at $120V$ then normally for the kettle to work at $500W$ power it should be able to have a current of $500/120=4.17A$. This would mean that the **resistance** of the kettle should be $$R=V/I=120/4.17=28.7\Omega$$.

Hence now in France the voltage is actually now $240V$ and at the $120V$ setting your resistance is still $28.7\Omega$. But the kettle is only built to withstand $4.17 A$ at this setting. But notice due to this resistance at $240V$ you get a current of $$I=V/R=240/28.7=8.36 A$$.
Thus you see that it is this reason why the circuit malfunctioned and produced high current as the current is not bound to the power rating but the **resistance of the kettle circuit which is changed by the voltage knob**.

Notice that your kettle would indeed work in France if the voltage knob was at $240V$ as then the resistance rating would be to ensure that $P=VI$ or $500=240*I$ or $I=2.083A$ is **maintained**. Then the resistance needed would effectively **increase**. $$R=V/I=240/2.083=115\Omega$$. Hence at $240V$ knob setting(which really means a **resistance** of $115\Omega$) would cause the current to be low enough for the kettle to work and not malfunction.

Comment: True, but to say P=VI, "that the kettle operates at the same power on a lower volatage by drawing more current" seems an adequate explaination. Sure, "how" that is done is to change the resistance, but readers should not start to feel that P-VI isn't applicable - it is. (what can be key is to distinguish "knowns" from "unknowns")

Comment: I agree, but what I wanted to say was that P=VI is important as a guide but it is not the core factor in directly finding the current in an appliance(especially in this situation), i.e. the power drawn ins't an inherent fixed quantity that determines current at a certain voltage, rather that inherent quantity is resistance which may affect the current and hence may even affect/change the power drawn at a certain voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that at a voltage of $2V$ the kettle element consists of two parts in **series** each of resistance $R$ ie a total resistance $2R$.

The power dissipated in the element is $\dfrac{(2V)^2}{2R}= \dfrac{2V^2}{R}$

---

If the element is to dissipate the same power when the voltage is halved to $V$ then a switching arrangement can used to now have the two parts of the element in **parallel** and thus having an effective resistance of $\dfrac R2$

The power dissipated in the element at this lower voltage is $\dfrac{V^2}{\left (\frac R2 \right)} = \dfrac{2V^2}{R}$ , the same as that at the higher voltage setting.

---

If whilst in the lower voltage $V$ setting the kettle is connected to a higher voltage $2V$ then the power dissipated in the element will be $\dfrac{(2V)^2}{\left (\frac R2 \right)}= \dfrac{8V^2}{R}$ which is **four** times the power rating.

If this happened then the current would be **four** times higher than it should be and this would trip the circuit breaker.

Comment: Just to precise the voltage in France is not 120V but 240V (230V to be exact)